# Is there a way to integrate VisualVM, or any free/open-source profiler, into Eclipse without a commercially licensed plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, profiler, visualvm

I see a few commercially available Java profilers that appear to use VisualVM, but I don't see anything under a free/open source license in the Eclipse Marketplace. The best option would be direct access to VisualVM into Eclipse directly. The next best option would be a plugin that allows me to configure and launch VisualVM on an Eclipse project. The worst-case option would be an alternative profiler that is similar in features to VisualVM.

I might be missing something, but if I wanted a Java profiler, preferably that uses VisualVM, that can be integrated into Eclipse, do I have any free and/or open-source options?

Comment: VisualVM is a standalone version of the Netbeans profiler.  I do not think it is trivial to integrate into Eclipse.

Comment: @Thorbjørn My understanding (which could be wrong) is that they decoupled it from NetBeans. For example, it is now included with the JDK. I'm not sure what kinds of programmatic interfaces are available, but since it has been part of the JDK, at least some way to easily activate it, connect it to your application, and run it from inside Eclipse should exist. Or, at least, it seems that way.

Comment: but I believe it still uses the Netbeans platform to create windows etc instead of Eclipse RCP.

Comment: @Thorbjørn That might be the case, but I'm not necessarily looking for it to be built into Eclipse, but something that will at least allow me to run an Eclipse project using VisualVM in order to conduct my profiling. Best case would be full integration. Acceptable would be a method to execute VisualVM on a project without leaving Eclipse.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try [Eclipse launcher for VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html).

Comment: I was searching on the VisualVM site and somehow missed this. It's not the best option, but it's better than manually configuring and running VisualVM. Since I don't think there's anything better (at least at this point in time), I'm going to accept this answer.